# DataFrame ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, anaconda

Hola que tal soy nueva con todo esto del Machine Learning y Data Science, y llevo unos días con un error de DataFrame con el pandas. Se supone que debo entrenar un modelo para que me retorne 5 números de 50 disponibles, y distinguir si fueron proporcionados por humanos o de manera aleatoria. hace falta mas código pero hasta aquí he podido trabajar.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.read_csv('azar_1.csv')

print(dataset)

randomdata = []
for i in range(dataset):
    randomdata.append(sorted(np.random.choice(50, 5, replace=False) + 1))
randomdata = np.array(randomdata)
randomdata = pd.DataFrame(randomdata,
                          index=[i + dataset for i in range(dataset)],
                          columns=['Nl', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'NS'])
```

Este es el código que he hecho hasta ahora,  y este es el TRACEBACK que me presenta:

```
[300 rows x 6 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1657, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 139, in __init__
    self._verify_integrity()

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 334, in _verify_integrity
    construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1694, in construction_error
    raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
```

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (300, 5), indices imply (6, 5)

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\****\Google Drive\EOI-Drive\MODULO3\Project\Juego_Azar_Spy.py", line 14, in <module>
    columns=['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5'])

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 464, in __init__
    mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 210, in init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1664, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1694, in construction_error
    raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
```

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (300, 5), indices imply (6, 5)

Comment: Hola Viannesa, bienvenida es [es.so]. Agrega siempre el código y los errores como texto, no como imágenes. Las imágenes pueden ser útiles, pero de forma accesoria. No permiten reproducir de forma simple el código al no poder copiar y pegar simplemente, dificultan la legibilidad del mismo (especialmente en dispositivos móviles) y no indizan para futuras búsquedas.

Comment: Simplemente copia y pega el código, luego lo seleccionas todo y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor, con ésto se formateará adecuadamente. Si tienes problemas con el formateo no te preocupes, déjalo como puedas y seguro que alguien edita la pregunta corrigiéndolo. Por cierto, ¿qué intentas hacer exactamente y qué es dataset en concreto?Un saludo.

Comment: Es un proyecto de juego al azar en el que debo entrar un modelo para que digga si los numeros fueron proporcionados por humanos de manera aleatoria

Comment: Ya he editado la entrada para que puedan tener mas información, gracias de antemano